# javascript json-p cross domain request

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, restful-url

Can you tell me what is wrong with this code, I am new to this and have no idea, I tried everything but I can not receive the data from the server.

the alert says [object Object], do you know what this means??:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sUrl =  "http://ops.epo.org/2.6.2/rest-


      // LOOP THROUGH EACH FAMILY MEMBER AND DO STUFF!
      alert(mValue)
    });
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm thinking you mean [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)?

Comment: So mValue is a "complex object" (e.g. not a string or number). **Look at the actual server response;** e.g. Firebug or Developer Tools to "know" what the format of the JSON is. There is not enough context here for "why" it is what it is ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert says that `mValue` is an object (of "class" `Object`, ie. a plain JS object) which was stringified by `alert` to its string representation `"[object Object]"`.

Use `console.log(mValue)` instead and inspect the element's properties in your developer console.

Comment: This is not *strictly* true. Consider: `function f () {}; alert(new f)` which will be "[object Object]" although it is not a "plain object".

Comment: OK, "plain" in this context should mean "not host object (which usually have a distinct class)", and no primitive wrapper or the like with special behaviour. Also, in his case it really is a plain object

Comment: How can I e.g. look for a specific property of mValue and put it for example in to a text field? I am sorry but I try since hours with no success. I need just an example.

Comment: What do you mean by "look for"? You can access them just as you already did with the properties of `oData`